# Cannot get email notifications in conky

Tags: email, conky

In my .conkyrc I want to be shown the number of emails on my provider's POP3 server.
Something like this

```
${pop3_unseen myserver myemail mypasswd -i 600 -p 995 -r 5}
```

only returns '0' as output, although there are always some. I have the variable from the conky objects list

https://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html

How do I troubleshoot this?

#### Edit:

It's a German provider (posteo.de).

I have installed fetchmail on my system now (Linux Mint 21 LTS Vanessa) and tried your proposal with the verbose option. It seems to work, since it returns a status output in the form of a number (zero by now). I will try again later and see if the number increases, and I will also play around with some other options maybe. And it even shows the total of messages on the server - exactly what I was after. It's just a bit long,

```
1553 Nachrichten für habae@posteo.de bei posteo.de (113599479 octets)
```

but I might be able to prune the first couple of characters and numbers with 'head' or so for my conky window.

Comment: What email provider is it? A lot of email services now won't allow basic password authentication like this. Some allow workarounds like generating individual app passwords, some may not. But I would use another tool like `fetchmail` on the command line to check that you can connect with your details. Something like `fetchmail -c -p POP3 -u myemail myserver` The -c option should return a status code to indicate if email is waiting or not without fetching anything.